# AttributeError: "instance has no attribute"

Tags: python

I am having a problem understanding why my code gives me this error

> AttributeError: "Tree instance has no attribute 'root'"

I am trying to implement a binary search tree and here is my code.

```
class Node:
     def __init__(self, value):
        self.val = value
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class Tree:

    def __init__(self, val):
        root = Node(val)

def main():
    tree = Tree(100);
    print tree.root.val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am new to python. Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `self.root` to tell the interpreter that the `Tree` class has a instance var named `root`.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.root = Node(val)
```